# Show ListPlot strange behaviour of label placement for small values of the y-coordinates

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling

I do not understand the placement of the last label in the simple example

```
Show[
 ListPlot[
  {Labeled[{0, .02}, "OK", Right]}
  ],
 ListPlot[
  {Labeled[{.5, .02}, "OK", Above]}
  ],
 ListPlot[
  {Labeled[{.6, .01}, "OK", Above]}
  ],
 ListPlot[
  {Labeled[{.7, .001}, "OK", Above]}
  ],
 ListPlot[
  {Labeled[{.8, .000001}, "OK", Above]}
  ],
 ListPlot[
  {Labeled[{.9, 0}, "??", Above]}
  ]
 ]
```

See the picture below. Is this a bug?

If so, can I control the placement more precisely, by explicitly giving the position, than with `Above`? I have not been able to find this in the documentation.

[image]

*Disclaimers.* In this simple example a simple workaround is provided by giving the $y$-coordinate a small nonzero value like for the penultimate point, but that does not seem to help in the more complicated figure for which I encountered this problem. Likewise, here the problem disappears when all points are just included in a single `ListPlot`, but that won't help me in the case I am really interested in. I use Mma v12.1.

Comment: I am not sure that it helps, but if you put this problematic plot to be first in the list, it works as expected.

Comment: specify a small plot range in the last plot: `ListPlot[{Labeled[{.9,0}, "??", Above]}, PlotRange->10^-5]`. The problem seems to be related to the fact that  symbolic positions like `Above` depend on the the plot range and  automatic plot  range calculation treats `0` and `0+$MachineEpsilon` quiet differently (try, for example, `ListPlot[{{.9,0.+$MachineEpsilon}}]` and `ListPlot[{{.9,0}}]`.

Comment: @kglr Thanks, that's very helpful! (And I didn't know about ```$MachineEpsilon```.) Just out of curiosity -- is it possible to give non-symbolic positions in ```Labeled```?

Comment: Jules, you can use `ListPlot[{Labeled[{.9, 0}, "Ok", {{.9, 0}, {.5, -.5}}]}]`. To see the effect of  changing `{.5, -.5}` try  `Manipulate[
 ListPlot[{Labeled[{.9, 0}, Framed@"Ok", {{.9, 0}, {a, b}}]}, 
  PlotStyle ->  Directive[AbsolutePointSize[Large], Opacity[1], 
    Red]], {{a, .5}, -2, 2}, {{b, .5}, -2, 2}]`